# Referencing UITextFields in a custom cell in a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfielddelegate

I have a static `UITableView` that has 5 cells like below:

[image: custom UITableViewCell]

When the user selects the top row I need to execute a method which will populate data into the second row.

When de-queing the cell's I added a target action like so:

```
[cell.upperTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(upperTextFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

I get notified of the event. How do I reference the second text view (find the `CellForRowAtIndexPath`) to enter data into it?

I can't use the `didSelectRow` since I have disable selection - the user can only tap into one of the provided TextFields.

Comment: one cell has one textfield or one cell has 5 textfields?

Comment: each cell has 2 textFields and 2 labels - the labels are on the right side.

Comment: may be this method help you to notify [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textFieldBeganEditing) 
                                             name:UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification object:nil];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom cell for that and find your cell object using CellForRowAtIndexPath method and now you can easily find your textfield like below.

```
MyCellView myCell = [myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:<your index path>];
myCell.firstTextField
```

or

```
myCell.secondTextField
```

If you want to change the text. You can easily change the text of textField.

Comment: I don't know the index path - upperTextFieldDidChange:(id)sender would only send me the textField - maybe I'm missing something there?

Comment: Den by using this id you can use id.superiew to get the current cell. Dont forget to check if it same class or not.

Comment: Thanks! Yea, I got it to work this way too. I like it a bit better since I don't have to use numeric tags.

Answer (score 1):

Add tag values to your UITextFields:

```
textField1.tag = 1;
textField1.tag = 2;
```

In your upperTextFieldDidChange: get reference to your superview of your textField and find view by tag:

```
-(void)upperTextFieldDidChange:(id)sender
{
    UITextFields *tf = (UITextFields*)sender;
    int currentTag = tf.tag;
    // Do any validation if needed
    //Get reference to text field superview
    UIView *v = [tf superview];
    // Get reference to your second text field
    int tfTag = currentTag == 1 ? 2 : 1;
    UITextField *anotherTextField = (UITextField*)[v viewWithTag: tfTag];
    // Execute your method do other stuff here
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you very much. I was missing the jump at UIView *v = [tf superview] and the the viewWithTag :)

Answer (score 0):

if think it would be easier by subclassing UITableViewCell and handle that internal in that cell. Then you could directly access the correct textfield.

Create a .h and .m wth

```
@interface YourCell : UITableViewCell
```

Then name that class in the interfacebuilder inspector section for your storyboard cell.
Then you call the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
YourCell *tempCell = (YourCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Comment: hmm. Can you explain a bit more? How would I call the subclass?